# When would a function's actual .length be insufficient for _.curry()

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lodash, redux-thunk, currying

I was running into a wonky situation where a function using `_.curry` on a  was invoking the function immediately. After reading the lodash docs, we figured out we needed to declare arity, thanks to the very well written docs:

> The arity of func may be specified if func.length is not sufficient.

However, I'm curious if anyone knows any actual examples of why this might happen (not necessarily the specific reason it happened in my codebase).

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to overwrite a function's length. Why don't you show us your function and hopefully somebody can explain where the problem came from?

Comment: Maybe I should ask the lodash maintainers, since they seem to be aware of a case where it wouldn't be "sufficient".

Comment: I can think of plenty situations where it wouldn't be sufficient. Why don't you tell us about your specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I'm curious if anyone knows any actual examples of why this might happen (not necessarily the specific reason it happened in my codebase).

Examples:

- The function uses the `arguments` object instead of formal parameters:

```js
function sum() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
    total += arguments[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log('length', sum.length);   // 0
console.log('result', sum(3, 4));
```

- The function uses a "rest" parameter:

```js
function sum(...values) {
  return values.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0);
}

console.log('length', sum.length);    // 0
console.log('result', sum(3, 4));
```

- The function has been partially evaluated or has gone through some other transformation:

```js
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }

var inc = _.partial(add, 1);

console.log('add length', add.length);        // 2
console.log('inc length', inc.length);        // 0
console.log('result', inc(8));

var squarePlusOne = _.flow(x => x * x, x => x + 1);

console.log('length', squarePlusOne.length);  // 0
console.log('result', squarePlusOne(7));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

- The function has more parameters than you actually want to curry (i.e. it has optional parameters)

```js
function combine(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + (z || 0);
}

console.log('length', combine.length);   // 3
console.log('result', combine(3, 4));
```